# Client - server socket byte transmission

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am sending a byte array from a client (android)

```
byte[] data = new byte[7];
    data[0] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[1] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[2] = (byte) 0xd1;
    data[3] = (byte) 0x01;
    data[4] = (byte) 0x00;//0xd1 + 0x00;
    data[5] = "}".getBytes()[0];
    data[6] = "}".getBytes()[0];
    os.write(data);  // os - Output stream
```

and in the server i am listening to it...

```
InputStream is = this.socket.getInputStream();
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

    // Set up input stream filters.
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    // Get the request line of the SMS request message.
    String requestLine = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(requestLine + "<---- Received message");
```

When i send such a data.. br.readLine() doesnt get called or stuck.. When i am sending just a string  from the client

os.writeBytes("Automated message");  it works jus fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readLine() is probably waiting for a line terminator before it returns. You can try the following:

```
byte[] data = new byte[8];
    data[0] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[1] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[2] = (byte) 0xd1;
    data[3] = (byte) 0x01;
    data[4] = (byte) 0x00;//0xd1 + 0x00;
    data[5] = "}".getBytes()[0];
    data[6] = "}".getBytes()[0];
    data[7] = "\r".getBytes()[0];
    os.write(data);  // os - Output stream
```